# How to append string with name 'kg' in input type number ? Angular ngModel

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-ngmodel

I need to append 'kg' string in my ngModel type number?
How to do it?

```
            <input (click)="singleClickForTraining(set)"
              [ngClass]="{ currentExe : currentSet === set }" 
              [(ngModel)]="set.reps" class="input-invisible-for-sets" type="number">
```

Comment: you shouldn't if you want to do it, change its type from number to text.

Answer (score 0):

Your input control is of "type" number. meaning it only accepts numeric values eg. 01234... etc.

to have your input control accept alpha-numeric(text and number) values you need to change the type to text. You should only consider doing this if 'kg' is part of the value of the input and not a description of what the value of the input is.

if the meaning or the context of your input control is a number or an entity that represents a number-value then you should always keep the type as a number and not text.
this protects you or other pieces of code and/or other developers using that field, such that they don't need to do any string manipulation to acquire/use the value of the input, considering there might be a need to sum the input in a calculation. eg. [100kg - 20kg] is incorrect and will fail.

if 'kg' is a description of the input then consider putting it in the label control to tell the user what exactly the input is for. eg. "Please enter your weight in 'kg'"... you can take this further and add a placeholder to the input

```
eg. <input type='number' placeholder='eg. 100kg' />"
```

you can even be fancy and use a :before or :after pseudo class on the input wrapper and give the content property a value of 'kg' and then style it appropriately to overlap onto the input.

this is inline with best practices from a ui/ux perspective as well as a back-end consideration.

theres many ways to put the 'kg' in there but lets create good code...

UPDATE:
I dont unserstand why you dont want to use a pseudo class, theres still many way it can be done. also have you considered using a range element.
check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lebwgj32/)

Comment: kg is only describe what user seting...only number is important but for user important is kg for describe. placeholder and pseude element is for me, bad solution. I need better solution

Comment: why is it bad... check out my updated answer with example

Answer (score -1):

You need to quote the string `'kg'` in `ngModel` or it will be evaluated as another scope variable.

```html
    <input [(ngModel)]="'kg' + set.reps" type="number">
```

or if type="number" is not necessary then you can do something like this as well:

```html
    <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]" [(ngModel)]="'kg' + set.reps" />
```

Hope it helps, if not feel free to ask further questions